# Expectation under a t-distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, closed-form-expressions, integral-transforms

Given parameters $\lambda, \nu>0$, a covariance matrix $R$, a mean vector $\mu \in R^p$, the Arellano-Valle and Bolfarine's generalized $t$ distribution is given by (see, for example, the book by Kotz and Nadarajah)
\begin{equation}
 f(x)=\frac{\Gamma((\nu+p)/2)}{(\pi)^\frac{p}{2}\Gamma(\nu/2)|R|^\frac{1}{2}}
\left[ 1+\frac{1}{\lambda}(x-\mu)^T R^{-1} (x-\mu) \right]^{-(\nu+p)/2},
\end{equation}
where $x \in R^p$.

I want to find the expectation, under $f(x)$ of something similar to the density, i.e.,
I want to evaluate

\begin{equation}
      \int_x f(x) \left[ 1+\frac{1}{\lambda_2}(x-\mu_2)^T R_2^{-1} (x-\mu_2) \right]^{-\nu_2} dx,
\end{equation}
where $R_2$ is a covariance matrix, $\mu_2$ is a vector, and $\lambda_2>0$.

Is there a closed form expression for this integral for $x \in R^p$? In 1-d?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure a closed-form expression is known in the literature, but I found this [paper](http://www.springerlink.com/index/6833356842Q37836.pdf) that describes other properties of that integral without solving it.

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` is broken. I'm also unable to find any snapshot saved on the Wayback Machine.